# Bookmarks and Filters

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am new to Power BI / Power BI Desktop and hoping someone can help me.  Our dashboards connect to a SQL Server Cube and uses a live connection.  As such, we are unable to do things like calculations on the Power BI side.  In our report, we have Bookmarks set with Filters, so that the report filters out unwanted data from the dashboards.  What we have found is that these work great, until you move environments from DEV to UAT to PROD, and after all the changes are done in DEV, when we move to UAT, we need to open the report with the UAT connection and reset all the filters, because the data in UAT is different than DEV because only a small subset is allowed in each environment.  So when we get to PROD, we need to again set the filters and bookmarks because the data has changed.  Is there a way to avoid this, in that you set them once in DEV, and do not need to set them for each environment?  Hopefully this question makes sense, but if not, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is different or incomplete between the DEV, UAT and Prod, then there is not a way to automatically update the filters and the bookmarks. You will always have to add them. The best way would be to replicate the same values in the DEV & UAT from PROD. This may not always be possible depending on the sensitivity of the data, or if you have to anonymise data.